# uTorrent program issues

Tags: installation

I had uTorrent installed. One day I found it gone from my installed programs and my shortcuts were all irrelevant, so I tried installing it again. I got an error  saying `we're sorry, the installer has encountered an unrecoverable error and must quit` `Error:permission denied;file: common.js;line:10`

After I press ok uTorrent opens and I get another error inside "`unable to load"HTA": unknown error!`, then I can continue my current downloads.

However I cant add any from other torrent sites and when I try downloading a torrent I get an error that `an older version of uTorrent is running already please try again`.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. I have edited your question for grammar and formatting, however please feel free to change this if you feel I have altered the meaning. What is your question?

Comment: thx a lot im not good with grammar

Answer (score 0):

uTorrent does not require any installation to properly function. Most likely, you deployed part of it's files in a area you don't have correct access. Just run it instead of installing it, and at the first load, set your paths where you want to save the data and the .torrent files, but make sure you have proper write permissions there.